# How to generate all JSON paths conditionally with jq

Tags: json, path, jq

I have arbitrarily nested JSON objects similar to below.

```
{
  "parent1" : "someval"`,
  "parent2" : {
     "a" : "someval",
     "b" : "someval"
   },
  "parent3" : {
     "child1" : { 
        "a" : "someval"
      },
     "child2" : { 
        "b" : "someval"
      }
   }
}
```

I need to recursively go through them and check to see if any parent has children keys `a` or `b`, or both, and generate the JSON path to that parent like so:

```
Output:
parent2 
parent3.child1
parent3.child2
```

I have tried using

```
jq -r 'path(..) | map (. | tostring) | join (".")
```

Which helps me generate all paths, but I haven't found a way to combine conditions like `has("a")` with `path` successfully. How can I go about achieving this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `index` to check if you keys are in the `path` array:

```
path(..) | select(index("a") or index("b")) | join(".")
```

```
"parent2.a"
"parent2.b"
"parent3.child1.a"
"parent3.child2.b"
```

#### [JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/S0mBX56p2Ik)

---

If you don't want the last key, you could add `[:-1]` to 'remove' the last index in each array to output:

```
path(..) | select(index("a") or index("b"))[:-1] | join(".")
```

```
"parent2"
"parent2"
"parent3.child1"
"parent3.child2"
```

#### [JqPlay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sTupEwb1tPm)